# Qt 4.8: loading SQL drivers from shared library/DLL

Tags: c++, macos, qt, sqlite

I'm using Qt 4.8.4 to write an application on both Mac OS and Windows. The program is made of an executable and a shared library/dll and it uses the SQLite driver.

Development is done primarily on Mac OS and that is my main concern today.

When in development/debug mode everything is fine, Qt loads its libraries from the hard-coded paths in the Frameworks.

When deploying the app it cannot load the libqsqlite.dylib plugin from my shared library. Both the application and the library use SQLite via the QSqlDatabase interface. The application seems to be loading the driver OK because it reads the qt.conf.

When deploying the app, at startup the shared lib, which can be used by other apps, fails to load the libqsqlite.dylib driver.

It's my understanding that Qt loads the drivers using QCoreApplication but the library doesn't use such class. I can't figure out how to instruct Qt to load the driver from the library pointing to the copy of the drivers in the bundle. The driver is in /Contents/PlugIns/sqldrivers .

I tried to load the driver manually in the entry point of the library by using the QPluginLoader class and the loading works, but Qt does not detect the driver in memory and so it tries to load it again and it fails as usual.

Some details:

- Mac OS 10.9
- Qt 4.8.4 compiled with XCode, used for two years without issues
- Application is deployed with macdeployqt

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should place libqsqlite.dylib in a folder named sqldrivers alongside the application executable binary. Also make sure that you put libQtSql.dylib beside your application binary.

Comment: It's already done and it doesn't work. The program sees it but the library doesn't it. I looked in the Qt code and it requires a QCoreApplication object to load the SQL plugin. A shared library/DLL does not have a QCoreApplication so there must be an alternative.